# Why the capacity of ResourcePool block is not changing on runTime in AnyLogic?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am using a variable to define the capacity of the ResourcePool block. Then, I am changing the variable value using an event, but the ResourcePool capacity is not getting updated."

[image]

let me know what is the reason behind that?
`your text`

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance I'm wrong here, but from what I understand what you are trying to do is not possible with the schedule object

the capacity when "on" is calculated in the beginning of the simulation and cannot be changed ever again. So changing the variable has no effect.

In order to solve this, you can use the same schedule object and have a `resourcePool.set_capacity(value)` command when you need to define the capacity. But you need the resource capacity to be defined "Directly" in your resourcePool object

And you will also be able to change the capacity freely at any time.